# Webservice call from Android failing

Tags: android, okhttp

Very new at Android development. Trying to call a webservice in Android Studio and getting this: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: SSL handshake timed out. I dont see traffic with wireshark and am not sure at what point its failing. Does not seem to leave the emulator.

EDIT: The webservice contains three methods, for lack of better term. I am not sure how to call the proper method in android. In powershell I call like this:

Powershell:

```
$myname = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri $URI -Namespace myname-class ssl
$myname.webservicemethod($qualifications,0,30)
```

Android:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button2);
        final TextView textview = findViewById(R.id.textView);

         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
         {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask()
                {
                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects)
                    {
                        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

                        HttpUrl.Builder urlBuilder = HttpUrl.parse("https://ip of webservice/pathvalue/WSDL/public/hostname/name").newBuilder();
                    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("username", "someuser");
                    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("password", "somepass");
                    urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("qualification", "Assigned Group=Admin Group");
                    String url = urlBuilder.build().toString();

                    Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url).build();
                    Response response = null;
                    try
                    {
                        response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                        return response.body().string();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
 return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Object o)
                {
                    textview.setText(o.toString());

                }
            }.execute();
        }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems your server does not responding. have you checked it out with curl or postman or other http request builders ... ?

Comment: The webservice I am calling is working. I can call it and get correct results from a powershell program I wrote to test it.

Comment: Check your emulator configurations. It may be a firewall thing. Here's a helpful link https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Answer (score 0):

I suspect preventing SocketTimeoutException is beyond our limit. One way to effectively handle it is to define a connection timeout and later handle it by using a try catch block. Hope this will helps

```
HttpUrlConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(7000); //set the timeout in milliseconds
```